# Do I need the expensive enterprise developer account in order to use TestFlightApp for beta testing?

Tags: iphone, ios, adhoc, ad-hoc-distribution, testflight

I don't understand yet how TestFlightApp manages to send my app to any tester I invite by email. Actually AdHoc Distribution is limited to 100 devices and here and there I read about Enterprise signed IPAs for no-limit beta testing.

So I need the enterprise account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, you do not. It works fine with a regular developer account. I use it all the time.

You are limited to 100 testers though, TestFlight does not get around that.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you need no more than 100 test devices, you'll be fine with the free version!

Comment: What do you mean by free version? Is there a paid TestFlight version which gets around the 100 devices?

Comment: Apologies, I meant that the free TestFlight service (don't know if there is a paid version) works great with a regular iOS account. The limit of 100 users isn't likely to be a problem. As little as five can give you excellent coverage according to this: http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20000319.html